# WSO2 Identity Server clustering: does each node in a cluster need to share a common SQL database?

Tags: wso2, cluster-computing, wso2-identity-server

We are evaluating WSO2 Identity Server, and are trying to understand how WSO2 Identity Server scales across multiple nodes.

The document https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Identity+Server+5.1.0+and+5.2.0 explains steps to follow to enable clustering, however the document links to database setup documentation that is common to the whole WSO2 suite, and not specifically for Identity Server.

I understand from the documentation that all WSO2 Identity Server nodes are required to share a set of clustered LDAP servers (when an LDAP server is in use).

Is each node in a WSO2 Identity Server cluster required to share a set of clustered SQL servers in addition to the above?

Alternatively, is it fine to have each node use a local database in the expectation that WSO2 Identity Server will communicate with other members of the cluster in order to keep all databases in sync?

Answer (score 0):

When clustering wso2 products, you can use a local db for WSO2CarbonDB (This will be used to store instance-specific data) But you have to share registrydb, userdb among all the nodes.
AFAIK wso2 will not do the db syncing if you use separate db for each node.

Comment: So to be explicit, to avoid any single point of failure, you will need to deploy multiple clustered WSO2 Identity Servers connecting to multiple clustered LDAPs and connecting to multiple clustered SQL servers?

Comment: yes, If you want that much availability you can set up like it. But there can be an inconsistency between clustered LDAPs and SQL servers. You can have 100% consistency by makes sure the data is synced properly, then you will lose the performance. It's your decision on which you need most. You can find the recommended deployment patterns of WSO2 IS here, https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Deployment+Patterns